# Chart not showing in crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am trying to show Charts using `crystal reports` in `vs2010` but `chart` is not showing up in the browser. it looks like the screenshot below.

[image]

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
dsSample ds = new dsSample(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.TableName = "Crystal Report Example";
dt = getAllOrders(); 
ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);

rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("graphReport.rpt"));
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to configure you web.config file to make crystal reports handle your charts and images in it. add following setting in the web.config file

-----In `<system.web>` section add

```
<httpHandlers>

      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>

    </httpHandlers>
```

This will handle you images and charts in crystal reports

Best of luck...